# Why are my HTTP status types overlapping?

Tags: haskell

I'm working with some HTTP code and getting a compiler warning when I build (using `stack build`) that warns of overlapping pattern matches in my cases that handle different HTTP responses. I'm using the packages

```
 import Network.HTTP.Types.Status (ok200, status203, Status)
 import Network.HTTP.Conduit
 import Network.HTTP.Types.Header
```

The code in question is:

```
 ... -- setup stuff for other functions.
 -- getHttpResponse just uses "httpLbs req mngr" with some additional error wrapping
 resp <- liftIO $ getHttpResponse mngr req
    case resp of
      Nothing -> ExceptT $ return $ Left $ create $ "could not get a response from " <> uri
      Just r -> case responseStatus r of
              ok200 -> do 
                  case decode (responseBody r) of
                    Nothing -> throwIOError $ "could not decode object from " <> uri
                    Just xx -> return $ Right (xx, responseStatus r)
              status203 -> do 
                  case decode (responseBody r) of
                    Nothing -> throwIOError $ "could not decode object from " <> uri 
                    Just xx -> return $ Left (xx, responseStatus r)   
              _ -> (throwIOError $ "non 200 server response "
                                  <> T.pack (show $ responseStatus r)
                                  <> " from " <> uri)
```

The warning that GHC gives me is:

> ```
> Pattern match(es) are overlapped
> In a case alternative:
>     status203 -> ...
>     _ -> ...
> ```

Both my 200 and 203 responses seem to be following the first route (returning a `Right`) and matching to `ok200`. To add to my confusion, I originally had a typo in my code where I had put `ok203` in place of `status203`. I'm not sure why, but that code still compiled and simply gave a similar warning message:

> ```
> Pattern match(es) are overlapped
> In a case alternative:
>     ok203-> ...
>     _ -> ...
> ```

despite ok203 not being defined in my code base or in any of the packages I'm using (at least that I could find).

Could anyone explain what is happening here? Why are these patterns overlapping? And, as a bonus, why did my code even compile with `ok203`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `ok203` and `status203` are *lower case*. So they're interpreted in patterns as variables to bind rather than constructors to match. If there are separate constructors for the different statuses, then you should use those. Otherwise, you should use guards and `==` to inspect statuses rather than trying to match on their values. This could look like

```
case responseStatus r of
  stat
    | stat == ok203 -> ...
    | stat == ... -> ...
    | otherwise -> ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm not sure what you mean by "If there are separate constructors for the different statuses, then you should use those." I'm fairly new to haskell and still learning. Am I looking for an upper-case type class (say Ok200 instead of ok200)? As far as I can tell, what i'm using are the constructors for the various `Status` objects.

Comment: Type classes have nothing to do with this. In Haskell, constructors always start with an upper case letter, while variables always start with a lower case one. This is true for both values and types. Operator syntax is a bit different, but don't worry about its details yet. Yes, there may be a constructor with a name like `Ok200`. It's also possible that these statuses are just numbers you need to compare with `==`. I'm not familiar with that particular library.

Comment: Ahh okay so if I wanted to continue with the case match, I would do something like matching on `Status { statusCode = 200}` then? I think guards are better for what I'm doing like you suggested but I'm just trying to understand the whole picture better.

Comment: @jkeuhlen, yes, or if you want to match on many you can pull out the number and case match on it. However, having now looked at the module, I'm quite convinced that you should use guards instead.